# custom rest service throws an error in SharePoint 2013

Tags: rest, web-services, ajax

I have come into a problem with a project at the customer. This project was built by someone else and he has left the company.

There is a rest service which runs in a different host name, but in the same server and SharePoint site runs in a different host name. The service is not working and it simply throws the word "Error" as exception. But in debug mode I see that it shows another error: `"SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied."`

Someone suggested that this is a cross domain issue.

**Update:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //$.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        //crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://resta/sites/beclaims/_layouts/15/ClaimsListService/ClaimsListService.svc/GetGroups",
    type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },success: function (a){
        alert("success");

     },error: function (a, e, r) {
        alert("error occurred: " + a.responseText);
    }
    }); 
});
```

**Update 2**
Now I am getting this error message.

```
---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
error occurred: 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en-us" dir="ltr">

<head><meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/><meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOHTMLINDEX" /><title>

    Error

</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css?rev=mU6O5kUqlpBzD0VDIFwe1Q%3D%3D"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/error.css?rev=nc1850SZNy60qTAeQIRxsA%3D%3D"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js?rev=ZCyl%2Bj%2B4NZLoeodWTEXQ0Q%3D%3D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=htz3HZ4_-KprzaWoySj_vzqAUvzxTy-ZkTm3ITYwelTLOc8hNRD41A7CQgYQigcJLKaW3kYg9rfqIlU0yldRwSudm6cMYwB6zSSi2hRuHgc5IlT9cRaJlIartww1DiZz8KQFUO_BWOwS6CLJqGrjvEv35ABvoydlKbueRmANdPQCcGmSQ1MWu161eGGlCTkK0&amp;t=6119e399"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/blank.js?rev=ZaOXZEobVwykPO9g8hq%2F8A%3D%3D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=UGql_BJowDYZF5u6as5_dSt60nnSFmZIlxfTK6w9VWJr-EHbKV-1sGAbjQ2cJkI4By_S3PYZGlQJcrO7lFcWlQ5R2qmAcUPX5wy10xUSNoPY5QKboH1El1b6hnXZ6qtSEhtpIIKlT5LTS9a9LCz8vwiBh6_9QhhAXwG3wxSX9Ckv2LEai5gNpKsDfzLLdjmW0&amp;t=6119e399"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("initstrings.js", "\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002f1033\u002finitstrings.js?rev=uNmvBiHdrBzcPQzXRpm\u00252FnQ\u00253D\u00253D");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("strings.js", "\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002f1033\u002fstrings.js?rev=DY9A0USYODVw86N0trJTSw\u00253D\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("strings.js", "initstrings.js");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sp.init.js", "\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fsp.init.js?rev=QI1y…
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

**Update 3**

Ok, the cause of the error above is this part of the code: `dataType: "json",`
Now, I don't get that error anymore, but I am still having the problem with the cross domain call.

How can I solve the cross domain call?

Comment: Can we see the code?  Assuming the REST call is made via javascript.

Comment: Why "crossDomain: true" is commented?

Comment: It did not work. So I commented it out.

Comment: I will give it a try again. Just a second.
Just tried it again but it does not work. I currently getting a strange error now. See my second update above.